# Add optional part in python regular expression

Tags: python

I want to add an optional part to my python expression:

```
myExp = re.compile("(.*)_(\d+)\.(\w+)")
```

so that
if my string is abc_34.txt, result.group(2) is 34
if my string is abc_2034.txt, results.group(2) is still 34

I tried `myExp = re.compile("(.*)_[20](\d+)\.(\w+)")`

but my results.groups(2) is 034 for the case of abc_2034.txt

Thanks F.J.

But I want to expand your solution and add a suffix.

so that if I put abc_203422.txt, results.group(2) is still 34

I tried "(.*)_(?:20)?(\d+)(?:22)?.(\w+)")
but I get 3422 instead of 34

Comment: Do you always want the second group to match exactly 2 digits?  Will the extra two digits always be '20'?

Comment: Do you want always the last two digits of second group?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use named groups instead.

Comment: "When you have a programing problem, and you think, "I will use a regex."  Now you have two problems". --someone famous

Comment: By the way, always put an r before the string you use for a regex, e.g. `r"...."`  Some of the regex escapes are the same as the string escapes, e.g. \b.  You don't want the double quote string constructor converting the \b to the ascii code for 'bell'.   When that happens, the regex engine will never see the characters \b, and therefore the \b in your pattern won't match a word boundary.  You might be tempted to commit suicide while trying to figure out why your \b won't match a word boundary.  So using an r before your pattern string is actually healthy for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myExp = re.compile("(.*)_(?:20)?(\d+)\.(\w+)")
```

The `?:` at the beginning of the group containing `20` makes this a non-capturing group, the `?` after that group makes it optional.  So `(?:20)?` means "optionally match `20`".

Answer (score 1):

```
strings = [
    "abc_34.txt", 
    "abc_2034.txt",  
]


for string in strings:
    first_part, ext = string.split(".")
    prefix, number = first_part.split("_")

    print prefix, number[-2:], ext


--output:--
abc 34 txt
abc 34 txt



import re

strings = [
    "abc_34.txt", 
    "abc_2034.txt",  
]

pattern = r"""
    ([^_]*)     #Match not an underscore, 0 or more times, captured in group 1
    _           #followed by an underscore
    \d*         #followed by a digit, 0 or more times, greedy
    (\d{2})     #followed by a digit, twice, captured in group 2
    [.]         #followed by a period
    (.*)        #followed by any character, 0 or more times, captured in group 3
"""


regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.X)  #ignore whitespace and comments in regex

for string in strings:
    md = re.match(regex, string)
    if md:
        print md.group(1), md.group(2), md.group(3)

--output:--
abc 34 txt
abc 34 txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're looking for this, but `?` is the re symbol for 0 or 1 times. or {0,2} which is a bit hacky for up to two optional [0-9]. I will think more on it.